# Congruency of triangles that share a side and angle measure

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

> For any triangle $\triangle ABC, \ \triangle A_0B_0C_0$, in a plane, if $|AB|=|A_0B_0|$ and $|\angle A| = |\angle A_0|$, then both triangles are congruent.

What I did was a proof by contraposition. Assume the conclusion $q$ is false, then the proposition is true if the original premise $p$ is also false — or it is false if $p$ is still true.

My attempt: Assume $\triangle ABC \not \cong \triangle A_0B_0C_0$.
Let $\triangle ABC$ be any triangle in a plane (that is not a right triangle). Then let $L$ be the segment perpendicular to $AB$ and also contain the point $C$ and the point $P$ that is on $AB$. Triangle $\triangle A_0B_0C_0$ has vertices $A_0=A, B_0=B, C_0=P\ne C$.

Since $\triangle ABC$ is not a right triangle and $\triangle A_0B_0C_0$ is, then they are not angle preserving, so they are not congruent. Since $A_0B_0$ coincide $AB$ as $A_0=A, B_0=B$ then $|AB|=|A_0B_0|$. However, $|\angle A|=|\angle A_0|$ still holds.

$|AB|=|A_0B_0|$ and $|\angle A| = |\angle A_0| $ Is still true, therefore by contraposition $\triangle ABC \not \cong \triangle A_0B_0C_0$.

Comment: Can't be true!  $C$ and $C_0$ are too free!

Comment: Take $(A,B,C,BC,CA,AB)=(30^\circ,30^\circ,120^\circ,1/\sqrt 3,1/\sqrt 3,1)$ and $(A_0,B_0,C_0,B_0C_0,C_0A_0,A_0B_0)=(30^\circ,120^\circ,30^\circ,1,\sqrt 3,1)$.